# Удаление четных слов в строке

Tags: c++, строки

Я пытался сделать удаление четных слов в строке, но мой код не корректно удаляет эти слова. В чем может быть проблема? Прошу прошения, если вопрос  выглядит плохо оформленным.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
 
 
int main()
{
    int beg, end,len;
    char text[1024];
    cout<<"Enter text(less than 1024 chars)\n";
    cin.getline(text,1024);
    
    for(int i = 0, iWord = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
    {
        if(text[i] == ' ')
        {
            
            while(text[i] == ' ')
            i++;
            beg = i;
            i++;
            while(text[i] != ' ')
                i++;
            while(text[i] == ' ')
                i++;
            i--;
            iWord++;
            end = i;
            if((iWord - 1) % 2 == 0)
            if(strcpy(&text[beg], &text[end]))
                text[strlen(text) - (end - beg)] = '\0';
            i -= 2;
        }
    }
    
    cout<<"String after removing odd words\n";
    cout<<text<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Тест]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strcpy(&text[beg], &text[end]);
```

Копирует также и '\0', не нужно его выставлять отдельно, да и strlen после копирования уже меньше, чем вы ожидаете.

Помимо пробела в качестве конца слова нужно ожидать также и конец строки, иначе можно считать последнее слово слишком длинным...

В конце итерации цикла необходимо правильно корректировать позицию счётчика.

---

Более менее исправленная версия:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    size_t beg, end;
    char *text = new char[1024];

    strcpy(text, "One Two Three Four Five Six");
    // cout<<"Enter text(less than 1024 chars)\n";
    // cin.getline(text,1024);
    std::cout << text << "\n";
    for(size_t i = 0, iWord = 0; text[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(text[i] == ' ' || text[i] == '\0')
        {
            while(text[i] == ' ') i++;
            beg = i;
            while(text[i] != ' ' && text[i] != '\0') i++;
            while(text[i] == ' ') i++;
            end = i;

            iWord++;
            if((iWord - 1) % 2 == 0) {
                strcpy(&text[beg], &text[end]);
            }
            i -= end - beg + 1; // correct iterator
            iWord--; // correct word cnt
        }
    }
    std::cout << text << "\n";
}
```

---

PS: если я правильно помню, поведение копирования пересекающихся массивов не определено. В истории Linux был [инцидент](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=638477) по этому поводу(только с memcpy). =)